# how to add a javascript action when i change the input's content?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make some validation using javacript, i need to show the user an alert when he/she changes the value of an input.

```
<input type="text" name="onchange" id="onchange" size="35" maxlength="50" />
```

Comment: Where is your js code?

Comment: `onchange` is a event! Having it as value of attribute is not gonna help!

Comment: use onchange="alert("hei!!!!")"

Comment: Better way is to use `document.getElementById('onchange).addEvntListener('input',function(){  alert(this.value);})`

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually I used onchange="alert('event')" as someone answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go

```
<input type="text" name="onchange" id="onchange" size="35" maxlength="50" 
     onchange="alert('Onchange event occured')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery `on input` function as the following

```
        $("#onchange").on("input", function() {
    alert("Change to " + this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind function to element:

```
var input = document.getElementById('onchange');

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    //something you want to do
});
```